# Flutter can't find txt file

Tags: flutter, dart, assets, txt

I'm trying to use the [INI Package](https://pub.dev/packages/ini/example) to read a file, but when I'm trying to access the file just by reading its contents I get the following error: No such  file or directory.

Here is the faulty code:

```
class _FactsListScreenState extends State<FactsListScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    File file = File("Assets/Facts/English.txt");
    Config config = Config.fromStrings(file.readAsLinesSync());
    print(config.sections());
```

Interesting, but when using `rootBundle.loadString("Assets/Facts/English.txt")` it works, but not when using `File("Assets/Facts/English.txt")`

I also need to mention that I'm running the app on an Android simulator, if that makes any difference.

Yes, I have included the folder in pubspec.yaml:

[image: pubspec.yaml screenshot]

Here is my file structure to show that the file is actually there:

[image: File Structure]

What's the problem with the code? Why it can't find the file?

Comment: assests/facts/english.txt,  you have to add the whole path including the file name in pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: Try adding only `Assets/` in your pubspect.yaml. See if that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use File to read files from assets due to File is a reference to a file on the file system. You can't access assets files by File.
Whenever you tried calling like

```
File file = File("Assets/Facts/English.txt");
```

it will try to read files from a device not from the app's assets folder.

You could use the below function to make file from assets.

```
Future<File> getImageFileFromAssets(String path) async {
  final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$path');

   final file = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$path');
    await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));

  return file;
}
```

Comment: Now it brings up the following error: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/data/user/0/org.codeclickers.factsapp/cache/assets/facts/English.txt' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: Don't add a full path just add a name in a path like only add English.txt and try

Answer (score 0):

You can change your pubspec file to only:

`Assets/`

And then call:

`File file = File("Facts/English.txt");`

Comment: Doesn't work...

Comment: I have added a little more explanation to my question, check it again, please.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your **Asset** directory to **assets** (small case). because as per the flutter official document (name libraries, packages, directories, and source files using lowercase_with_underscores.fileextension)check this [link](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#do-name-libraries-and-source-files-using-lowercase_with_underscores) for reference.

so in your case do following things:

```
1. Rename your Asset directory to assets 
2. Rename subdirectories to audio, facts
3. also rename file to english.txt
```

use string file path like thin `'assets/facts/english.txt'`

Comment: I have tried, but still, the same problem. I forgot to mention that I'm running the app in debug mode on an Android Simulator.

Comment: Can you uninstall the app. Then clean and build app and run again. And make sure asset folder name must in small case.